# What do you call words made from common English words?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for words that are built by combining other ordinary English words together?

For example:

- catfish = cat + fish
- firetruck = fire + truck
- farmhouse = farm + house
- birdcage = bird + cage

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They’re called [compound words](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)).

According to Wikipedia:

> Compounding occurs when two or more words or signs are joined to make one longer word or sign. The meaning of the compound may be similar to or different from the meaning of its components in isolation.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/about-nouns/nouns-compound-nouns):

> Many compound nouns are written as one word, but some are written with hyphens or spaces. In modern English, hyphens are less common than they were in the past.
>
> Examples of one word:
>
> - bathroom sheepdog windscreen
>
> Examples of hyphens:
>
> - check-in fire-fighter son-in-law
>
> Examples of spaces:
>
> - bottle opener New Year’s Day Prime Minister

Comment: @Ubihatt - What additional information are you looking for? There's a link to Wikipedia with the relevant parts copied into the body of the answer so it's not a link-only answer.

Comment: @SomethingDark answer has to be written here. You simply can't provide a link.

Comment: @Ubihatt - the answer _is_ written here. The correct term is "compound words." There is no additional information required.

Comment: @SomethingDark well it is apparent that you are not aware of EL & U guidelines. So, please stop snapping back. I'll suggest you to follow the guidelines directing EL & U. Read- [How do I write a good answer?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Ubihatt - Please do not mistake my brevity for insult. I am fully aware of the guidelines for this site and believe this answer falls well within the guidelines laid out in the "Answer the question" section of the link you provided. The question specifically asks for the term for words that are built by combining other words. This term is called a "compound word," as the answer states. If you believe the answer can be improved, feel free to [edit it](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Comment: @tchrist is this answer okay?

Comment: @SomethingDark Sure, something is fishy about this answer and up-votes. There should be a close clique to support your view and the answer. In-spite of my argument being correct. Someone is supporting your comment with up-vote. Looks suspicious. Anyways, I have flagged it. Let's see what mods have to say.

Comment: You should be voting to close the question rather than giving one line answers.